# js measuring the difference between visible height and total height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I measure the total height of the div and visible height on the screen in js?

For example, if the total height of the div is 1000px and currently only 450px are visible on the screen.

Because only 450px is visible and there are still 650px left to be scrolled (remaining px), I am trying to trigger an alert when this remaining px becomes less than 100px.

In other words, out of 1000px, if user scrolls down and the remaining px is less than 100px, I want to trigger an alert.

I see that i can use something like ".offset().top" but I am not so sure how to .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset - div.offsetTop > 900) {
    alert('Less than 100px of div visible');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

- `window.pageYOffset` is current scroll position from top,
- `div.offsetTop` is `div`'s position from top

Difference between both is number of pixels scrolled beyond top of the `div`. More than 900px beyond the top of 1000px-high element means less than 100px of it left.

---

You can also change that `if` to

```
if (window.pageYOffset - (div.offsetTop + div.scrollHeight) > -100) {
```

`div.scrollHeight` is height of the `div`, so the entire above expression stands for number of pixels scrolled beyond **bottom** of the `div`. And `-100` beyond the bottom means 100px left to it.